# Sendmail has stopped working after editing resolv.conf. Why?

Tags: domain-name-system, sendmail, resolv.conf

I previously resolved an issue with upstream timeout errors by changing the nameservers in my resolv.conf to Google's nameservers.

While the upstream timeout and 504 errors were sorted by doing this, now sendmail refuses to "sendmail".

Testing sendmail with:

echo "Subject: test" | /usr/lib/sendmail -v UncleStanley@re****mail.com

```
UncleStanley@re****mail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 sd-2***8.de**ox.ro ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4; Mon, 7   Sep 2015 05:16:37 +0200; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO sd-2***8.de**ox.ro
250-sd-2***8.de**ox.ro Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<root@sd-2***8.de**ox.ro> SIZE=14 AUTH=root@sd-2***8.de**ox.ro
250 2.1.0 <root@sd-2***8.de**ox.ro>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<UncleStanley@re****mail.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <UncleStanley@re****mail.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
```

> > > .
> > >           050 ... Connecting to [smtp-server] via relay...
> > >           050 ... aliased to o****extr
> > >           050 o****extr... Connecting to local...
> > >           050 o****extr... Sent
> > >           250 2.0.0 t873Gbx9003582 Message accepted for delivery
> > >       sephopower@gmail.com... Sent (t873Gbx9003582 Message accepted for delivery)
> > >           Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
> > >       QUIT
> > >           221 2.0.0 sd-2***8.de**ox.ro closing connection

Now I suppose that would seem okay. The mail was sent but it isn't, as the message has not been sent.

In the mail.info log I have found

```
Sep  7 05:49:27 sd-28368 sendmail[4020]: t873nRpj004020: from=root, size=14, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201509070349.t873nRpj004020@sd-2***8.de**ox.ro>, rel$
Sep  7 05:49:27 sd-28368 sm-mta[4021]: t873nR8I004021: from=<root@sd-2***8.de**ox.ro>, size=307, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201509070349.t873nRpj004020@sd-2$
Sep  7 05:49:27 sd-28368 sm-mta[4021]: t873nR8I004021: to=<UncleStanley@re****mail.com>, ctladdr=<root@sd-2***8.de**ox.ro> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00,$
Sep  7 05:49:27 sd-28368 sm-mta[4021]: t873nR8I004021: t873nR8J004021: DSN: Host unknown (Name server: [smtp-server]: host not found)
Sep  7 05:49:27 sd-28368 sm-mta[4021]: t873nR8J004021: to=o****extr, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Sep  7 05:49:27 sd-28368 sendmail[4020]: t873nRpj004020: to=UncleStanley@re****mail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=300$
```

DSN: Host unknown (Name server: [smtp-server]: host not found)

Now after a bit of reading I have learned that I may use an external stmp-server.

But my thing is I did not have to do any of that before I was forced to change the nameservers in resolv.conf.

I'm sure that there is probably something very simple that I am missing but I cannot find a solution anywhere. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

My resolv.conf is below:

```
domain on****.net
search on****.net
nameserver 62.265.16.6
nameserver 62.265.16.7
```

*The IP addresses in the above resolv.conf, aren't the IP addresses issued with the server. They have been edited.*

Comment: I don't see the contents of your resolv.conf here. What did you put in it?

Comment: By any chance was your original resolv.conf pointing to local nameservers?  Ones that might have an RR for 'smtp-server'?  And did you transfer your 'search' directives to the new resolv.conf?

Comment: Is the log entry with the DSN in any way redacted, or is `smtp-server` what the error message actually says?

Comment: I have included the original resolv.conf, but edited the ip addressees. I had not altered the messages from the log in any way.

Comment: Those are not valid IP addresses. And even if they were valid, they are probably not Google nameservers. [Please do not obfuscate anything](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: I know Michael, I had edited the IP addresses in the submitted resolv.conf, The original problem I had was 504 errors using the set of IP addresses that I was give. Changing to googl's addresses solved that error, but sendmail had stopped working, which is where I am now stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the edits, I didn't think the edited information would be relevant to thew issue. Do you actually need to know the proper IP addresses? If so I will include them, but I don't see why. I suppose the problem as it stands is why won't sendmail function if I use google's nameservers?

Comment: If you do 'dig +search \@original.nameserver.ip address smtp-server' do you get an answer? If so, do you get the same result  from 'dig +search \@8.8.8.8.8 smtp-server'? (edit: ignore the backslash, it wouldn't let me post without it)